# ¿Cómo debería ser la lógica del siguiente arreglo con objetos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Me encuentro practicando React, y estoy haciendo un juego simple de piedra papel y tijeras siguiendo un tutorial, les enseño el pequeño código que llevo hasta ahora.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
// El arreglo dentro de los objetos, es para indicar que opción le gana a que opción.
const options = [
  {id: 0, name: "Piedra", emoji: "", beats: [2]},
  {id: 1, name: "Papel", emoji: "", beats: [0]},
  {id: 2, name: "Tijera", emoji: "✂", beats: [1]}
]

export default function Game() {
  return <>
  </>
}
```

La lógica sería la siguiente, la piedra tiene un id 0, y se dice que esta le gana al id 2 , eso quiere decir que le ganaría a la tijera. ¿Está bien planteado esto?

Comment: Creo que deberías generar una matriz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como planteado "si" ... i no.

Pero lo que le falta es la lógica para determinar si gana o no tu elección vs la otra.

Por que se puede hacer incluso sin id, ni beats. Eso ya depende de como tu enfoques luego la lógica.

Lo que és un poco raro (almenos para mi) es asignar un "id" a una casilla de un array. Por que ya tienen un "id" asignado que es la posicion que ocupa en el array.

Es decir:

```
options[0]
```

Hará siempre referencia a "Piedra", tenga o no tenga el atributo "id".

Luego que dentro del atributo beats pongas un array con un único numero es raro tambien, sería más normal poner simplemente

```
beats: 2
```

El array sería entendible si pudiera ganar a más de una cosa, pero como solo va a ganar a una cosa pues no hace falta un array, solo un número.

Comment: Muchas gracias ferter!